# how resolve? error: symbol cannot find

Tags: java, algorithm

I am not able to compile a file, it gives error on line 12 and 13. Appears the following error name:

> GradeBook.java: 12: error: can not find symbol courseName = name;
>   (this line appears an arrow pointing to the "n" of "name.") Symbol:
>   variable name location: class GradeBook
>
> GradeBook.java: 13: error: can not find symbol instructorName =
>   teacher; (this line appears an arrow pointing to the "p" for
>   "teacher") symbol: variable Professor location: class GradeBook

```
public class GradeBook
{
private String courseName; // nome do curso para esse GradeBook
private String instructorName; // nome do professor para esse GradeBook


public GradeBook (String courseName, String instructorName)
{
    courseName = name; 
    instructorName = professor;
} 


public void setCourseName (String name)
{
    courseName = name; 
} 


public String getCourseName()
{
    return courseName;
} 


public void setInstructorName (String professor)
{
    instructorName = professor; 
} 


public String getInstructorName()
{
    return instructorName;
} 


public void displayMessage()
{
    System.out.printf("Welcome to the GradeBook for \n %s! \n",
        getCourseName() );
    System.out.printf("This course is presented by: \n %s \n",
        getInstructorName() );    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it in its constructor you are referencing two variables that do not exist 'name' and 'teacher'.

```
public GradeBook (String courseName, String instructorName)
{
    courseName = name; // variable "name" is not declared anywhere
    instructorName = professor; // variable "teacher" was not declared.
} // fim do constructor
```

To fix this change courseName by name and teacher for instructorName which are the parameters of the constructor.

Looks like this:

```
public GradeBook (String courseName, String instructorName)
{
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.instructorName = instructorName;
} // fim do construtor
```

Answer (score 0):

You change your constructor argument name to name and professor instead of name and instructorname